# MacBook Pro with Touch Bar not saving Screenshots

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, finder, macos, screen-capture

I bought a new MacBook Pro and everything was running smoothly, but some days ago I noticed that the screenshots (<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>) are not saving to the Desktop (it was working before), only saving to the clipboard.

- It is not a wrong shortcut since I can hear the screenshot sound.
- I have already tried to Force Quit Finder or restart the Mac and none
  of these worked.
- I have already tried this terminal command  `defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Desktop/` and `killall SystemUIServer` but they didnt work as well.
- I do not have DropBox Installed

I am a developer so I install new dependencies every day, it may have changed some default configurations?

Comment: What key combinations are you using to take the screenshots?

Comment: Command + Shift + 3. (Just added this to the question to be more clear)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured it out. I have the latest mac, that comes with the Touch Bar. So I noticed that when a press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> (without the <kbd>control</kbd>, so it should save directly to the desktop) my Touch Bar shows this:

[image: Touchbar Screenshot]

So, as you can see, it was saving to the Clipboard, instead of the Desktop (I probably did this by touching the Touch Bar unintentionally). Then, if you did everything that I wrote at my question and nothing happened, probably this is your problem too.

How to solve this:

- Press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>, so your Touch Bar will look like the image above.
- So, all you got to do is change the option that is selected at the **Save to:** section to **Desktop**.

Doing this, both <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> will now save your Screen Shots to the Desktop.

Comment: this needs to be upvoted more :)

Comment: Amazing, thank you! When choosing **Desktop** you are still able to change the directory using the `defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Pictures/Screenshots/` command later.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using this terminal command  :

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Desktop/
```

Try a different approach using this terminal command

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location /Users/yourusername/Desktop/
```

Obviously replace “yourusername” with your username

Comment: i already tried this and it didn't work as well

Comment: This worked for me just fine in Catalina.